# Install RWekajars On Ubuntu

Tags: java, r, ubuntu, installation, weka

I try to install the R package "RWekajars". Unfortunatly I get the following error message:

```
* installing *source* package ‘RWekajars’ ...
** Paket ‘RWekajars’ erfolgreich entpackt und MD5 Summen überprüft
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: getsp
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: getsp
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: getsp.  Program will exit.
./configure: Zeile 50: test: -ge: Einstelliger (unärer) Operator erwartet.
./configure: Zeile 51: test: -eq: Einstelliger (unärer) Operator erwartet.
Need at least Java version 1.5/5.0.
```

I use Ubuntu 11.04 but I have the same problem on Ubuntu 10.10.

Refreshing the R - Java configuration with

```
R CMD javareconf
```

did *not* help.

I have the problem on two maschines, one runs Oracle Java (1.6.0_26) and the other one runs OpenJDK (1.6.0). So the error message

```
Need at least Java version 1.5/5.0
```

seems not justified. Also there is only one java version installed.

Answer (score 3):

Solution (at least for ubuntu):

Open a terminal and execute

```
export CLASSPATH=/usr/share/R/share/java
```

in the same terminal window

```
R
> install.packages("RWekajars")
```

Done.

How to get to the solution (this should help you if you are running another OS or distribution):

To solve this problem I first downloaded the package source using

```
download.packages("RWekajars")
```

in the configure script you see that R determines the java version using

```
java_version=`${JAVA} getsp "java.version"`
```

I used

```
locate getsp
```

and found:

```
/usr/share/R/share/java/getsp.class
```

So the getsp class is present but R cannot find it. This is why we set the CLASSPATH variable to /usr/share/R/share/java before executing R. This way R knows where to find the getsp program during the installation process. If your getsp.class is in another directory you have to change the path in the export statement.

Hope this helps someone, because it took me a while to figure that out.

PS: This problem does not occur on ubuntu 12.04 - at least for now.