# R CMD javareconf on Cygwin

Tags: java, r, cygwin, classpath

I am trying to get Java hooked up with R on Cygwin. I get a `could not load or find main class getsp` error when I try `R CMD javareconf`.

Here are the steps that I have taken:

1. Added the location of `javac` to the `PATH`. Checked that `javac` and `java` work.
2. As per advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10855525/install-rwekajars-on-ubuntu), I figured that I could add the location of the `getsp` class to my classpath. Added the variable `CLASSPATH` to my *Windows* variables, and made sure that it was visible from within Cygwin using an `echo $CLASSPATH`. I tried adding both Cygwin type locations `/lib/R/share/java` and a  DOS path.

I still get that `getsp` is not found. How can I ensure that `getsp` is found by R?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cygwin is simply not supported by R, and it is best to keep the Cygwin `$PATH` away from the one used with R.

You may want to look into MSys which sits on top of the MinGW tool chain that R uses.